# Python - List sum itens from lists different len - "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

When I try to run this code below I received

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'"

I need to sum items from lists.

Python code:

```
 !pip install more-itertools  
 import itertools as it  

 input_total=[]  
 inputs_1 = input().split()  
 inputs_1 = list(map(int, inputs_1))  
 inputs_2 = input().split()  
 inputs_2 = list(map(int, inputs_2))  
 input_total.append([inputs_1, inputs_2])  
 result = [sum(x) for x in it.zip_longest(*input_total, fillvalue=0)]  
 print(result)
```

Samples:

```
 inputs_1 =[1, 2, 3]  
 inputs_2 =[1, 2]
```

expected result is `[2,4,3]`

```
 inputs_1 =[3, 2, 3]  
 inputs_2 =[4, 2, 2]
```

expected result is `[7,4,5]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Answer (score 0):

Change `input_total.append([inputs_1, inputs_2])` to `input_total += [inputs_1, inputs_2]`

You appended input_total with a list of your lists, so it looks like `input_total = [[inputs_1, inputs_2], ]`, and then tried to perform your additions on that.

Answer (score 0):

`input_total.append([inputs_1, inputs_2])` makes `input_total` a nested list (`print(input_total)` to see for yourself).

Then `[sum(x) for x in it.zip_longest(*input_total ...)` tries to sum two lists with the default value of `0`, which is what causes the error.

If you did not mean for `input_total` to be a nested list, change `input_total.append([inputs_1, inputs_2])` to `input_total = [inputs_1, inputs_2]).

```
import itertools as it

inputs_1 = input().split()
inputs_1 = list(map(int, inputs_1))
inputs_2 = input().split()
inputs_2 = list(map(int, inputs_2))
input_total = [inputs_1, inputs_2]
result = [sum(x) for x in it.zip_longest(*input_total, fillvalue=0)]
print(result)
```